# IndexError: tuple index out of range, when trying to print model object

Tags: python, django, models

here's my model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reviews = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Review")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Book object: {}>".format(self.title)
```

In the shell, here's the error when I try to print with Book.objects.all():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File 
 "/django/db/models/query.py", line 235, in __repr__
return '<QuerySet %r>' % data
File "/models.py", line 86, in __repr__
return "<Book object: {}>".format(self.title)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `"<Book object: {}>".format(self.title)` != `"<Book object: {}>".format(*self.title)`

Comment: And `self.title` is empty.

Comment: edited to reflect the correct error message (without the *)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the error and the links of code. I am 100% sure there is a typo somewhere and you are carrying over that typo across stackoverflow

Comment: Try changing `'<QuerySet %r>' % data` to `'<QuerySet %r>' % (data)`

Comment: sorry I'm a newbie. That was in the tracback/error. I just copy and pasted from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __repr__(self):
    """
    Just do this instead and move on with your life
    """
    return "<Book object: %s>" % (self.title)
```

Comment: Yeah, still getting the error with that. Must be deeper in my code. But I wouldn't even know what to post here. Thanks though.

Comment: Okay, I just exited, re-migrated (no changes) and did it again, and it magically worked. I'm sure it wasn't magic, but I'm not complaining. Thanks all.